# Stabilize 220 voltage when the fluctuation is too much

Tags: voltage, stabilizer

I live in just outside of a city limit of a  third tier city of a third world country. The recommended voltage is 220 V.

The problem is the voltage here drops till around 110 V.

I had added multiple combination of systems as shown in image below but the voltage fluctuates too much even the stabilized ones with a difference of over 40 V+/- and I constantly battles the sound of beeps and relay clicks.

[image]

Some Technical Information:

PC UPS - works only with voltage when it is above 150 V else it cut off and take load to a 7 Ah battery inbuilt and hence shut down so was the reason to buy a stabilizer mentioned below.

Triple booster voltage stabilizer does work and the output is between 200-250 V BUT looks like a case of a sudden drop when relay switches so voltage drops below say 150 for a second which is very annoying and also causing relays of UPS to fire.

Inverter does the job as bypass switch only when the power supply is working - so electric company is supplying power else when the electric supply goes everything is back to 220 V - pure sine wave.

I am concerned about few appliances as of now namely

PC Desktop - 60 W (Pentium G4560)
CCTVs - ~40 W
Monitor - 30 W
Routers etc - 30 W

- Overall under 200 W

XBOX may be - don't use it yet because of such a power crisis
Thermal printer - returned it because it didn't worked with UPS

QUERIES:

1. Can I connect an extra inverter with already existing (inverter with 200 Ah 12 V battery) and run a load of say 100 W directly? Any risk involved. Snapshot below

[image]

I had also looked into servo stabilizers but most of them only worked when minimum voltage is 170 V.

Now the inverters I mentioned also work as UPS but only when the output voltage don't drops below 170 V.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Also not a great culture to accept the items back by the sellers!

Or any possible solutions?

Comment: What does "third tier city" mean, and what's the significance? In China it's apparently a [small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weifang) [town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhenjiang) with only about 10 million people.

Comment: @pipe Nothing like that - just meant a small city where government agencies (power supply) ones take a blind eye ignoring the obvious common issues the citizens face

Answer (score 1):

Simplest I can think of is a wide range (100-240 V) 200+ W battery charger to charge your batteries and run an inverter off it.

A motorized autotransformer which you mentioned would do the job too down to the current capacity of it (half the input voltage and you will need double the current). Problem is that they are slow so if you have servo’d down for say 140 V and grid jumps back to 220 V, you will have 346 V on the output and possibly saturate your autotransformer as well. As much leverage as it gives you in one end, equally much the system will gain to “bite” you.

Comment: I was also about to do the same - one inverter (basically the ones available here are act a charger and inverter both) for charging and other to act as a inverter but do you think the voltage can cause issue. Like while charging the voltage is around ~14 V on batteries so using another inverter on 14 V can be problematic as it is not ~12 V

Comment: @Moons I’ve never run into an inverter which could not cope with 14 V. You should be fine.

Comment: Just did it. Worked well though kept a load of under 120 watt as of now from secondary inverter while the primary worked as usual for charging and discharging (during power cut) for fans, lights etc.

Comment: Good. Now you just need a wide range battery charger or possibly CC-CV power supply. Set it for 13.4-13.6 V.